# how to increase wordpress speed if my site have many plugins and big data

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, varnish, cloudflare

approximately 1 million woocommerce products.
Wp-rocket already enabled with cloudflare,
With Varnish cache,
and i use 20 active plugins.
Server: intel Xeon E5 6 cores, 24 GB RAM With SSD memory: With CPANEL WHM
Can help me optimize my Server and WP

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] .  This also should probably go to ServerFault.com instead of SO since it's way too broad for a SO question and is not about a specific bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you might want to use a tool like http://www.webpagetest.org to identify any problem areas.

From the waterfall view, if the time to first byte is much more than 500ms then you want to focus on your server config.

If the delay is from time to first byte to start render then examine the results want to figure out why.

You'll also see what if any improvements can be gained from compressing images and reducing file sizes.

Concatenating files almost always gets good results so make sure you are using the WP Rocket option to concatenate CSS and JS files (Static Files → Combine files)

On large CMS sites had good results installing Google's [PageSpeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/).

Here's an [overview of the filters available with PageSpeed](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/configuration) once it's installed.

One the things I like about PageSpeed is that you have good control over how you configure it, and it's working at the server level, so it will give you options which aren't available at the plugin level.

Good luck!